# how to collapse blank space when no Ads is return in AMP page

Tags: html, google-dfp, amp-html

The problem happens in AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) page.

Question:

I setup Ad EXchange for the advertising in my AMP.
How to collapse blank spaces when AdEX does not have ads to serve. Can you provide me a demo code?

I have read Github documentation about [window.context.noContentAvailable](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/ads#ad-resizing), but I still confusing where I should call this function (window.context.noContentAvailable) and where should I call window.context.requestResize(width, height) to collapse the ads position when there are no Ads returned.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
</head>
<body style = "background-color: green;">

   <amp-ad width="300"
      height="200"
      type="doubleclick"
      data-slot="/4119129/doesnt-exist"
      style= "background-color:lightgrey;">
    <div placeholder>
        <!-- <iframe src ="amphtml/3p/frame.max.html"> -->
        <div>
            sdsd
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.parent.context.onResizeSuccess(function (requestedHeight) {
                    console.log('success');
                    // body...
                })
                window.parent.context.onResizeDenied(function(requestedHeight){
                    console.log('failed');
                })
                window.parent.context.requestedResize(3,3);
            </script>

        </div>

    <!--    </iframe> -->
    </div>
  </amp-ad>

  <amp-ad width="300"
      height="200"
      type="doubleclick"
      data-slot="/4119129/doesnt-exist"
                  style= "background-color:yellow;">
    <div fallback>
     <div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.parent.context.onResizeSuccess(function (requestedHeight) {
                    console.log('success');
                    // body...
                })
                window.parent.context.onResizeDenied(function(requestedHeight){
                    console.log('failed');
                })
                window.parent.context.requestedResize(3,3);
            </script>
    </div>
    </div>
  </amp-ad>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the fallback attribute as described here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/builtins/amp-ad.md#no-ad-available to indicate what should happen when the ad slot isn't filled.

Don't try to insert your own Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Ads can request to be hidden, when there is nothing to show. AMP will only execute this request if it can be performed without disrupting users.

I know that doubleclick is currently sending these requests when appropriate, but I do not know about other ad networks. If in doubt, get in touch with their support.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the fallback placeholder here:
https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-ad/
(The GitHub link above is no longer valid.)

```html
<amp-ad width="300" height="250" type="foo">
  <div fallback>No ad for you</div>
</amp-ad>
```

Comment: Please offer more info about why your solution works instead of "read this"

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester the amp-ad component does this automatically and you can still override this behavior with the fallback element and some custom css:
https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-ad/#no-ad-available